# Laravel recursive jobs limited to 22

Tags: laravel, jobs

I am calling a Laravel job recursively as in the example.

```
class ThisJob implements ShouldQueue
{
private $job;
public function __construct($job)
{
$this->job = $job;
}

public function handle()
{
 //do stuff with $this->job

 $job = getNextJob();
 if(object_exists($job){
     ThisJob::dispatch($job);
}
}
```

The job is taken from a database table. I find that only 22 jobs get processed. Is there some limit on the amount of jobs that can be processed in this way?

Comment: How long do the jobs take to process and what is your `max_execution_time` setting? Are jobs being dispatched synchronously?

Comment: It's not a time out problem. the whole thing takes a couple of seconds.

Comment: Any more information, such as error logs? Which queue driver are you using?